# output array data into two colums instead of a single column

Tags: php, arrays, output

I have a code line of

```
<?php echo "\n" . $options_menu[$i]; ?>
```

which is an array of product attributes and gives an output of

130mm ( £3.99 )
160mm ( £5.49 )
180mm ( £5.99 )
200mm ( £6.99 )

with a radio button in front of each option for selection.

What i want to do is to reformat the output like this:

130mm ( £3.99 )       160mm ( £5.49 )
180mm ( £5.99 )        200mm ( £6.99 )

Is there a simple method to do this in php? So far the only suggestion i've found via search engine is to use tables.

I should add that the contents of this array could be different on other products, sometimes having 3 options, others having 7 or 8.
The goal is to always have them output as 1st in column one, 2nd in column two, 3rd in column 1 and so on.

Thanks for any advice and input.

Comment: are you on cli? (Noting that you use `\n` ...)

Comment: @bwoebi It's a code line from Zen Cart version 1.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be for tables.

```
<?php

    $options_menu = array("123", "456", "789", "abc", "def");

    $line_length = 2;

    echo '<table><tr>';
    for($i = 1; $i <= count($options_menu); $i++){
        printf("<td>%s</td>", $options_menu[$i - 1]);
        if($i % $line_length == 0) echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    echo '</table></tr>';

?>
```

Comment: That just gives me an output as 123456 789abc def, so not moving to a new line when column 1 is next output, and column 1 column 2 output has no separation at all. 
Any suggestion on fixing those because the basic principal is there.

Comment: Glad I could help It would be nice if you marked this as a solution ^_^

Comment: Any idea how i can get separation between the output of column one and column two? At the moment they are literally next to each other as 123456 instead of 123 456